# Can I use <picture> for both height and width-constrained images?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, srcset

I have a slideshow sort of thing where images will expand as large as they can, but not exceed the viewport's width or height. Basically `object-fit: contain`.

I'd like to make these images responsive, since "as large as they can" for a phone and a great big desktop is quite the difference. I can't use `<img srcset>` because right now, it only does screen density (`x` descriptors) or width (`w` descriptors). So that leaves `<picture>` to manually make the selection logic myself.

I started with:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(orientation:portrait)"
          sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px"
          srcset="300.jpg 300w, 500.jpg 500w, 800.jpg 800w, 1200.jpg 1200w">
  <source sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px"
          srcset="300.jpg 300w, 500.jpg 500w, 800.jpg 800w, 1200.jpg 1200w">
  <img src="default.jpg" alt="a man slipping on a banana peel">
</picture>
```

But it's not as simple as the screen's orientation, since the actual aspect ratios involved can get pretty exotic, both for viewports (very tall phones, browser toolbars, etc.) and for the images themselves; the same image might be width-constrained on one screen, but height-constrained on another. I figure I can write a script that parses out the aspect ratios, but I'm stumped on the logic to turn that into a meaningful `srcset` and `sizes` list.

**Ideally** `<img srcset>` will [get the `h` descriptor soon](https://github.com/ResponsiveImagesCG/picture-element/issues/86), but I'd like to hack something together that will work now.

Comment: My head is currently not working, but you should only need to change sizes and in case you do everything with JS, you need to only compute one sizes value in pixel, so not so hard. (I might try to do a lazySizes plugin for this).

Comment: In general if it is always the viewport and not a smaller element you are using, than you have if it is width constrained always sizes="100vw" and if it is height constrained sizes="calc(100vh * (heightOfImage / widthOfImage))"

Comment: For the basic proof-of-concept, yeah, it'll be the entire viewport, but in production it will be images inside various containers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I got it (1/2) is equal to (width/height):

```
<img 
    srcset="http://lorempixel.com/960/1920/sports/10/w1920/ 960w"
    sizes="(min-aspect-ratio: 1/2) calc(100vh * (1 / 2))"
    />
```

Or with more code:

```
<img
    srcset="http://lorempixel.com/960/1920/sports/10/w1920/ 960w"
    sizes="(min-aspect-ratio: 1/2) calc(100vh * (1 / 2)), 100vw"
    />
```

---

As a side note: I also have written a script that automatically calculates the right sizes for parent height/width constrained sizes. See here the [parent-fit script](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/parent-fit).

Comment: `aspect-ratio`! Why didn't I remember that? The `calc` is also much appreciated.

Comment: For very thin viewports, would I back that up with a `(max-aspect-ratio: 1/2)` as well?

Comment: i was researching sooo long to find this! thanks a lot

Comment: ok, so what i do is insert the aspect ratio of the image? for a landscape image with ratio 1.5, which is displayed max-with & max-height 90% i can use this: 

sizes="(min-aspect-ratio: 1.5) 90vh, 90vw"

is this correct?